# I couldn't implement requireJs to my node-cron project

Tags: node.js, cron, requirejs, node-modules

I create a basic node project with a html file. I created this basic js including node-cron:

```
const cron = require('node-cron')
cron.schedule('* * * * * *', () =>{
    console.log('Hello world')
})
```

I basically need to log 'Hello world' every second.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:1:14`

I see that i need to implement requireJs to my project, i did search in https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html website but i couldn't figure out how to do it. I need help.

Comment: Your code runs fine with node (put it in a `test.js` and run `node test.js`). How do you try to run it? Do you want to run it in a browser?

Comment: Do you try to run this in a browser?

Comment: @some-user yes. I want to run it on browser side.

Comment: `node-cron` is for node, not for browser. You could try to leverage e.g. `cron-schedule`. What do you want to use this cronjob for?

Comment: I want the website to run a block of code at regular intervals. I searched for it and i was recommended to node-cron